# BFS and DFS of a graph in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have been trying to do a BFS and DFS of my graph. I have tried everything but still cannot figure out what is wrong with my algorithm. Please help me with this.

I send the vertices with is my vector that points to the vertexes of my graph to the bfs and bfs in order to go through it and seek for the correct values. I am new to this and am having a lot of problem trying to solve it. It would be nice if someone could go through my code and see where I am wrong in my algorithm. I hope a fresh pair of eyes would be able to detect the problem.

It does show the output but is wrong!

This is my input values for graph::
5 1, 
5 2, 
5 3, 
1 4, 
1 6

Here 1 is the edge of 5, 2 is the edge of 5, 3 is the edge of 5 and so on....

And this is the output I get:
for BFS:
5,1,2,3,4,6

for DFS:
5,4,3,2,1,5

**Here is my algorithm for it:**

```
#ifndef SORT_HPP
#define SORT_HPP

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include "clsVertex.hpp"
#include "clsFileGraph.hpp"
#include "clsGraph.hpp";

class bfs : public clsGraph{
    int vert;

public:
    bfs(int s, vector<clsVertex*> verticies); //prints BFS traversal from a given source

};

class dfs: public clsGraph{
    int vert;
    list<int> adj;

public:
    dfs(int s, vector<clsVertex*> verticies);   //prints DFS traversal from a given source

};

bfs::bfs(int s, vector<clsVertex*> verticies){

    bool *visited = new bool[verticies.size()]; //creates a new boolean array of the size of the graph

    for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i++){ //loops till the end of the graph
        int x = verticies[i]->ID;   //gets the value of each vertex
            //cout << "The val: " << verticies[i]->ID << endl;
            visited[x] = false; //marks that vertex as unvisited i.e: visited = false
    }

    list<int> queue;    //creates a queue
    visited[s] = true;  //marks the starting point as visited
    queue.push_back(s); //adds the starting point to the queue
    cout << endl << "The breath first sort is as follows:-" << endl << endl;
    while (queue.size() != 0){  //loops until the size of the queue is 0 
        for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i++){ //loops 
            int y = verticies[i]->edges.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                int z = verticies[i]->edges[j]->ID;

                if (visited[z]== false){
                    visited[z] = true;
                    queue.push_back(z);
                }

            }
        }
        cout << s << ",";
        queue.pop_front();
        if (queue.size() == 0)
            goto here;
        s = queue.front();

    }
    here:
    cout << ID << " " << graphType << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i++){
        cout << verticies[i]->ID << "->";
        for (int j = 0; j < verticies[i]->edges.size(); j++){
            cout << verticies[i]->edges[j]->ID << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl << "Done" << endl << endl;
}




// DFS traversal of the vertices reachable from v. It uses recursive DFSUtil()
dfs::dfs(int s, vector<clsVertex*> verticies)
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool *visited = new bool[verticies.size()]; //creates a new boolean array of the size of the graph

    for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i++){ //loops till the end of the graph
        int x = verticies[i]->ID;   //gets the value of each vertex
        //cout << "The val: " << verticies[i]->ID << endl;
        visited[x] = false; //marks that vertex as unvisited i.e: visited = false
    }
    stack <int> depth;
    visited[s] = true;
    depth.push(s);
    //cout << s << ",";
    while (depth.size() != 0){  //loops until the size of the queue is 0 
        for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i++){ //loops 
            int y = verticies[i]->edges.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                int z = verticies[i]->edges[j]->ID;

                if (visited[z] == false){
                    visited[z] = true;
                    depth.push(z);
                }

            }
        }
        cout << s << ",";
        depth.pop();
        if (depth.size() == 0)
            goto there;
        s = depth.top();

    }
there:
    cout << "done";

}
#endif
```

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to a list?  You should almost never need a pointer to a container.

Comment: which one is wrong? BFS or DFS? Also, It might help if you posted the incorrect output you get.

Comment: I think both of them are wrong. I will add the input and outputs in the question as well.

Comment: @YRK: BFS results looks right to me, which is surprising because that's the harder algorithm

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks. I was confused on whether it was right or wrong. But I still am having a hard time figuring out the correct answer for DFS.

Comment: For DFS with `5` as a start, any of these would be right: `514623, 514632, 521463, 531462, 523146, 532146, 516423, 516432, 521643, 531642, 523164, 532164`.  The obvious algorithm would choose the first one, though the rest are equally valid.  However, your result has two `5`s and no `6`s!

Answer (score 2):

Your BFS method isn't working because you're adding vertices to your queue all out of order. You should replace the inside of your `while ( queue.size > 0 )` loop with something like:

```
s = queue.pop_front();
for ( int i = 0; i < vertices[s]->edges.size(); i++ ) {
    int tmp = vertices[s]->edges[i]->ID;
    if ( !visited[tmp] ) {
        visited[tmp] = true;
        queue.push_back(tmp);
    }
}
cout << s << " ";
```

As you have it at the moment, you add vertex 1's neighbours, then vertex 2's, and don't even reference your supposed starting point s. You need to add only the neighbours of whichever vertex is currently at the front of your queue.

Comment: His BFS output is right, though I admit I hadn't read the code.  His DFS output is clearly wrong though, it lists `5` twice and `6` not at all.

Comment: @Mooing Duck My guess is that it's a fluke that his BFS output is right, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @YRK: You should read the code and understand how it works rather than simply copy pasting it. This should print all of the values when used properly, and only prints `5` when used improperly.